# Use of @BeanProperty for setter generation only

Tags: scala

Is it possible to use the Scala @BeanProperty annotation to create only the setter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know [`@BeanProperty`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/BeanProperty.html) synthesizes getter for `val` fields and setter as well for `var`. It is not possible to generate only setters, hence you must write the setter explicitly and do not use `@BeanProperty`:

```
private var status = ""

def setStatus(s: String) { 
  this.status = s 
}
```

Note the `private` field modifier. Without it the `status()` Scala-style getter will still be generated. For some reason it is generated as well with `private var`, but it's private.

Comment: thanks for the answer. If I remember right you need to use private[this] to suppress the Scala accessors.

Comment: Scala accessors are generated for a `private` field so that an inner class can call them.